# How to apply backround image to div on hover- jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, background, hover

I want to add a background image to this div:

```
<div class="logo-main"></div>
```

But my script isn't working:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('.logo-main');
    $('.logo-main').hover(function() {
        div.css({ 'background': 'url(images/slides/glare.png)' }); 
        )};
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: any error in the console

Comment: what do you mean by not working

Comment: make sure you are giving right path to image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try background-image instead (and replace : with ,)..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('.logo-main');
    $('.logo-main').hover(function() {
        div.css({ 'background-image', 'url(images/slides/glare.png)' }); 
        )};
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = $('.logo-main');
    div.hover(function() {
        div.css({
                    'background' : 'url(images/slides/glare.png)'
                        });
            });
});
```

It can be simpliefied as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.logo-main').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({
                    'background' : 'url(images/slides/glare.png)'
                });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4QSHR/)

But probably what you want is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.logo-main').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'url(images/slides/glare.png)');
    }, function(){
        $(this).css('background', '');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4QSHR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You needn't be doing this via JavaScript since this is supported out of box with just CSS.

```
.logo-main {

}

.logo-main:hover {
    background-image: url(images/slides/glare.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background on a hover event simply by adding this to your stylesheet (css)...

```
.logo-main:hover {
    background: url(images/slides/glare.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alex: Here I have done one POC for you. Please find my code here....

HTML:

```
            <div class="logo-main"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo-main{
      background-    
         image:url(http://tommytoy.typepad.com/.a/6a0133f3a4072c970b016301ec8627970d-550wi);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:0 0;
        width:350px;
        height:165px;
        }
```

---

### Jquery Code:

```
  $('.logo-main').mouseover(function() {
       $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 100%')
    .mouseout(function() {
     $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0%') ;
    });
   });
```

---

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/PvgcE/1/)